# How to check added adsens ads in nextjs project (locally)

Tags: next.js, adsense

Help me understand why I can't see the added ads

My SEO (OpenGraph) component data

```
<Head>
 <Script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" crossOrigin="anonymous"></Script>
</Head>
```

This is where I add ads

```
<AdSense.Google
   client='ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   slot='myslot'
   style={{display: 'block'}}
   format='auto'
   data-full-width-responsive='true'
 />
```

But after adding this, I don't see it on the site when I run the project through `yarn dev`

*Of course, where xxxxxxx and myslot are, I insert my data

I just tried to follow the example of this article https://www.mridul.tech/blogs/how-to-add-google-adsense-in-next-js

Comment: and how to test ads on localhost?

Comment: Looking at the article you posted, they are specifically using `  strategy="afterInteractive"` on the `Script` tag, however you do not have that. This might fix the issue.

Comment: @rguarascia.ts Actually no, it doesn't work either, but it seems the problem is that in adsense settings you need to specify the domain localhost:3000